# Wrapping InstallShield Executable with ClickOnce

Tags: clickonce, installshield

I have an executable that I create using InstallShield. I want to be able to use ClickOnce to wrap this executable. Is there a way for ClickOnce to wrap the InstallShield executable?

Answer (score 0):

to create a ClickOnce installer you can create wrapper around your generated .msi either in C++/C# then pass the msiexec / i command to   with .msi in different process in silent mode from your wrapper app , moreover you can have your own progress bar to calculate the installation progress.